# Название типа дорожного ограждения

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется этот тип дорожного ограждения?

Comment: Информацию для ответа я загуглил за 2 минуты, хотя до этого никогда дорожными барьерами не интересовался. Вы уже третий день задаёте вопрос с этой картинкой. Зачем?

Comment: Использовали поиск по картинкам?

Comment: Нет, ввел запрос "дорожные барьеры" и посмотрел какие они бывают.

Answer (score 0):

Это водоналивной барьер.

> Водоналивные барьеры – незаменимое оборудование для ремонта и
>   строительства дорог, тоннелей и мостов. Оно предназначено для
>   разграничения транспортных потоков, а также их перенаправления. Чтобы
>   водоналивные барьеры были устойчивее, их заполняют водой.